# MD5 algorithm working in java even after disabling it in $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/java.security

Tags: java, md5, java-security, fips

I have disabled the MD5 algorithm use adding the following in `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/java.security` file. But I still I am able to run the code that use MD5 algorithms.

```
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, SHA1 jdkCA & usage TLSServer
jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, RSA keySize < 1024
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024
```

---

But I am still able run the following code that use MD5

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class MD5 {
    public static String getMd5(String input)
    {
        try {

            // Static getInstance method is called with hashing MD5
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

            // digest() method is called to calculate message digest
            // of an input digest() return array of byte
            byte[] messageDigest = md.digest(input.getBytes());

            // Convert byte array into signum representation
            BigInteger no = new BigInteger(1, messageDigest);

            // Convert message digest into hex value
            String hashtext = no.toString(16);
            while (hashtext.length() < 32) {
                hashtext = "0" + hashtext;
            }
            return hashtext;
        }

        // For specifying wrong message digest algorithms
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    // Driver code
    public static void main(String args[]) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
    {
        String s = "TESTFORMD%";
        System.out.println("Your HashCode Generated by MD5 is: " + getMd5(s));
    }
}
```

Comment: Go through this link it may help you. : - https://helpx.adobe.com/aem-forms/kb/java-update-compatability-md5.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Security policy configured in `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/java.security` affects how JVM will handle security related functions; it has nothing to do with what algorithms you *explicitly* (try to) use in your code.

For example:

- `jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms` disables algorithms used to verify signed jar files
- `jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms` disables algorithms used for certificates (also affects key lengths)
- `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` disables algorithms used for TLS cipher negotiation

So when you disable MD5 in security configuration, you are actually telling JVM not to use/trust MD5 for jar signing, certificates and TLS negotiation. The actual MD5 implementation is still there for you to use in `MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")`.